# how to add same text field to the same view controller when i click on button each time in objective c x-code6

Tags: ios, objective-c

i have code

```
UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(18, 350, 309, 35)];
textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
textField.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];
textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
textField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
textField.delegate = self;
[self.view addSubview:textField];..i tried like this..
```

but i want 
when i click add button ,each time one text field will be added to my view controller with different positions...

Thanks in Advance.....

Comment: your question is not clear , can you explain little bit more

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if(![self.view viewWithTag:44]){

UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(18, 350, 309, 35)];
textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
textField.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];
textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
textField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
textField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
    textField.delegate = self;
    textField.tag = 44;


    [self.view addSubview:textField];
}
```